# How do pilots avoid thunderstorms at night over the pacific en route to Australia where there is no radar? And what if a large front develops?

Tags: weather, night-flying, oceanic

While there is some limited radar on board for pilots, we hear that there is no radar over the ocean which is why flight locations are estimated. As the distance between the United States and Australia is lengthy, how do pilots avoid thunderstorms over the Pacific en route to Australia at night, and what did they do about them If a large front develops in their way?

Comment: Look out the window and see if you see lightning?  Even in a small plane, it's possible to see thunderstorms ~100 miles away, say storms in west central Nevada from over the Sacramento area.

Comment: Keep in mind that route is dotted with islands, and many have runways and weather stations.

Comment: The on-board radar is not some limited backup tool, it's the primary tool whenever you have it, even if there is coverage from ground radars.

Answer (score 13):

You get by on your airborne weather radar which is good out to about 80 miles.  You may also get help from other pilots ahead of you on your route providing PIREPS to ATC on HF, or talking to you directly if you are close enough to use VHF between each other.  But as far as picking your way around cells, besides being able to see them if you are in the clear, your own weather radar is all there is.

The main limitation of airborne WR is shadowing due to signal attenuation in rain, where the really nasty stuff is hidden (looks black as if the sky was empty) behind less nasty stuff.  Even with the modern radar there is a bit of skill and experience required to interpret the returns and not get fooled by shadows.

Comment: There's also data from weather satellites before the flight, and flex-routes via ACARS from the company.

Comment: @ymb1: And why couldn't commercial planes use satellite internet to get info from weather satellites while en route?

Comment: Just to emphasise, the point is that the plane has its own weather radar set. It's not reliant on somebody else's radar to know where the rain is.

Comment: Internet based weather radar is not real time and there is enough of a delay in presentation to be a problem.  Pilots flying IFR in the US using an internet based weather overlay on their flat panel displays as if it was airborne weather radar have gotten into serious trouble because cells had moved significantly from where it was depicted.

Comment: @jamesqf satellite weather is only good for getting an overall picture of a system.  As far as non-airborne sources go, you need ground based doppler radar to see exactly where cells are within a weather system, which is what you are really concerned with.

Comment: @John K: It's quite possible to detect lightning from orbit, even geostationary orbit, in near real-time: https://www.nesdis.noaa.gov/content/tracking-lightning-space-how-satellites-keep-you-safe-during-thunderstorms  Of course this doesn't detect all weather, but at ~30K ft I think you're above just about everything but thunderstorms.

Comment: @jamesqf but you need to be detecting water not so much lightening, and you need to do it with precision, within a mile or two.  The only other weather issue that gets you into trouble, except when close the ground, is icing and WxR doesn't help you there in the first place.  IFR flying is a risky business when conducted w/o WxR if there is any convective activity on a flight.

Comment: @John K: I don't follow your reasoning here.  Thunderstorms have lightning, by definition.  (I'm not saying that there aren't other kinds of weather you might want to avoid, but that's not what the question is asking.)  Nor do I see why you need to locate T-storms within a mile or two.  Certainly I'd be much happier giving them a wide berth, since (at least at the SEL level) you can get turbulence &c many miles from the actual storm.

Comment: The protocol in the airline business is to keep about 20 miles away from the edge of a cell, preferably upwind because hail tends to be toward the downwind side.  To know that you want at least want to be sure of being that distance +/- a couple miles.  The other thing is the worst part of the storm, to avoid at all costs, is the rain shaft, the core in other words. Lightening can be happening quite a distance from that, so knowing where lightening is without knowing where the water is is a problem. Lightening strikes are far less of a hazard than flying into the rain shaft.